# Parsed Json array shows undefined in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Following is my json data:

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "count": 3,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "602a2d4427e5ac1f5c8e897b",
            "survey_id": "602a5de91d4f0000ec004b94",
            "parent_question_id": "",
            "is_required": "1",
            "is_active": "1",
            "options": [
                {
                    "_id": "604b22c53b57d53fdc8c43f3",
                    "question_id": "602a2d4427e5ac1f5c8e897b",
                    "option_type_id": "602a2b0127e5ac1f5c8e8976",
                    "option_details": "He/She is good.",
                    "is_active": "1"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "604b22df3b57d53fdc8c43f5",
                    "question_id": "602a2d4427e5ac1f5c8e897b",
                    "option_type_id": "602a2b0127e5ac1f5c8e8976",
                    "option_details": "He/She is Average.",
                    "is_active": "1"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "604b22e63b57d53fdc8c43f6",
                    "question_id": "602a2d4427e5ac1f5c8e897b",
                    "option_type_id": "602a2b0127e5ac1f5c8e8976",
                    "option_details": "He/She is Poor.",
                    "is_active": "1"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "604b22d33b57d53fdc8c43f4",
                    "question_id": "602a2d4427e5ac1f5c8e897b",
                    "option_type_id": "602a2b0127e5ac1f5c8e8976",
                    "option_details": "He/She is Excellent.",
                    "is_active": "1"
                }
            ],
            "qustion_type": {
                "_id": "602a2b2627e5ac1f5c8e8978",
                "question_type": "Multie Radio",
                "is_active": "1"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Here I want to fetch the data of "option_details" which is inside the "option" array. I am able to get the option array.

Following is my code:

```
return 
  axios.get(api call here)
  .then((results) => {
    results.data.data.map(quesobj => {
      ques.push(quesobj.question_text);
    })
    console.log(ques);
    results.data.data.map(questypeobj => {
      questype.push(questypeobj.qustion_type.question_type);
    })
    results.data.data.map(optionobj => {
      option.push(optionobj.options);
    })
    console.log("Hello");
    console.log(option);
    console.log(option[0]);
    console.log(option[0].option_details);
    conv.add('Thank you');
  })
```

Here in the console when I print the option it display the option array which is coming from the api. but when I print option[0] it comes [] and when I print option[0].option_details it comes undefined. How do I solve this?

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

#### What is going on

In your json data, `options` is an array. So, this line :

`option.push(optionobj.options)`

will push some arrays to your `option` variable. In the end, `option` is an **array of array**, `option[0]` is an array, and `option[0].option_details` is undefined.

#### Suggestion

If I understand correctly, you want `option` to be an array that contains all the items from `options` attribute. You can use the spread operator to do that, change from :

`option.push(optionobj.options)`

to :

`option.push(...optionobj.options);`

the spread operator will push all the items in `optionobj.options` (not the array itself, that's the difference) to `option`

You can find more info about spread syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: sorry but that did not helped

Comment: What did it do when you tried that wasn't what you expected?